# Allowing clients to talk to the server in order

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, client

I'm confused with how I'm wanting clients to talk to the server in order. For example, I'm creating a multiplayer tic tac toe game, where 2 clients will connect to the game server. The clients then take turns to put in the coordinates of the x's. However, when I use a `break` on my while loop, it only lets them enter once, before disconnecting the socket. How do I do it such that the clients are just temporarily blocked while the other client answers?

EDIT: I do not intend to use multithreading for this purpose.

Server (truncated for reading purposes):

```
try {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Awaiting connection!");
            Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Player " + noOfPlayers + " has connected!");
            noOfPlayers ++;
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            while (!newGame.checkWinner()) {
                out.println(newGame.currentPlayer());
                input = in.readLine();
                x = Integer.parseInt(input.split("\\,+")[0]);
                y = Integer.parseInt(input.split("\\,+")[1]);
                newGame.addPoint(x, y);
                out.println("Moved");
                if (newGame.checkWinner()) {
                    System.out.println("The winner is " + newGame.currentPlayer());
                    out.println("The winner is " + newGame.currentPlayer());
                    server.close();
                    break;
                }
                else if (newGame.boardFilledUp()) {
                    newGame.loadBoard();
                    out.println("It's a draw!");
                    server.close();
                    break;
                }
                newGame.loadBoard();
                newGame.changePlayer();
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Client (truncated for reading purposes):

```
while (true) {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        // Read input from server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        // Read input from client
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter your coordinates in x,y form: ");
        String userInput;
        char serverOutput;
        serverOutput = in.readLine().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Current player is " + serverOutput);
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("You sent: " + userInput);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You just tell your client "Wait for the other to move".

Comment: @BalazsVago you mean letting the client check if there is a string acknowledgement from the server?

Comment: Always control the game from the server side, letting anything to be controlled from the client side may lead to "cheating" :). And yes, let the client click anywhere, but let the client know what server thinks about it.

Comment: Yes, my game functions are running server side! It's a console version of tic tac toe for now. I've added my code in the question so maybe you could help me take a look? If I'm not wrong I think it has something to do with the readLines() method.

Comment: Why do you break the game main loop after you flip the players?!

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I was just debugging it. The problem here is that both clients aren't connected at the same time! One will connect first, and after I put a series of coordinates into it, it will just get stuck and the 2nd client will never connect!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. I didn't flush the PrintWriter.